# cant save data on update method

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to save data from the average result of nilai tema table to nilai akhir table. but it shows an error 'array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer'.

this is my update method

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $nilai = nilaiTema::find($id);
    $rataP = ($request->input('p_nilai1') + $request->input('p_nilai2') + $request->input('p_nilai3')) / 3;
    $rataK = ($request->input('k_nilai1') + $request->input('k_nilai2') + $request->input('k_nilai3')) / 3;
    $nilai->p_nilai1 = $request->input('p_nilai1');
    $nilai->p_nilai2 = $request->input('p_nilai2');
    $nilai->p_nilai3 = $request->input('p_nilai3');
    $nilai->p_rata = $rataP;
    $nilai->k_nilai1 = $request->input('k_nilai1');
    $nilai->k_nilai2 = $request->input('k_nilai2');
    $nilai->k_nilai3 = $request->input('k_nilai3');
    $nilai->k_rata = $rataK;
    $nilai->save();

    $nilaiRataPenalaran = DB::table('nilai_temas')
    ->where([
        ['idKelas','=',$nilai->idKelas],
        ['mataPelajaran','=','   Pendidikan Agama dan Budi Pekerti']
    ])
    ->avg('p_rata');
    $nilaiRataKetrampilan = DB::table('nilai_temas')
    ->where([
        ['idKelas','=',$nilai->idKelas],
        ['mataPelajaran','=','   Pendidikan Agama dan Budi Pekerti']
    ])
    ->avg('k_rata');

    $nilaiAkhir = nilaiUtsUas::all()
    ->where([
        ['idKelas','=',$nilai->idKelas],
        ['mataPelajaran','=',$nilai->mataPelajaran]
    ])-first();
    $nilaiAkhir->nilaiPenalaran=$nilaiRataPenalaran;
    $nilaiAkhir->nilaiKetrampilan=$nilaiRataKetrampilan;
    $nilaiAkhir->save();

    return redirect('/daftarSiswa')->with('success', 'jadwal telah di rubah!');
}
```

my model is empty because the relationship is in the MySql database, and I'm sure the problem does not come from the relationship.

Comment: are you trying to pass data in laravel without model?

Comment: no, the model of nilaiTema and nilaiUtsUas is exist